# Expectation of number of links to N selected nodes in a network

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Take a directed graph denoted by its adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}$.  It is a probabilistic graph -- the nodes of $\mathbf{A}$ *might* be linked, and the entries are probabilities between 0 and 1.

Say I select $N$ nodes.  What is the expectation of the number of links to selected nodes, for a random node?

More concretely:  say I have Sneeches on Beaches.  None have stars.  They might know each other, hence the probabilistic adjacency matrix.  I pick $N$ and give them stars.  For a random Sneech, how many starred Sneeches do I expect that she knows?

Is this possible analytically, or do I need to go and simulate?

Edit:  what I'm really looking for is $E[X] = f(N)$, where $X$ is the number of links to selected nodes $S$, and $N$ is the number of selected nodes in the network.

Edit2:  I suppose that I could do it analytically in the following inefficient way:

1. Construct $\mathbf{S_N}\equiv$all possible $S$ vectors for a given $N$
2. Take the mean of the row-wise means of $\mathbf{S_N'A}$

But the size of $\mathbf{S}$ will generally be huge.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand clearly.  Can you say if this is correct : given a vertex set $S$, pick a node $v$ at random outside of $S$.  You're looking for the expected number of neighbors of $v$ in $S$.  Is that right ?

Comment: Exactly.  Though I suppose that $v$ could be in $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph and let $S \subseteq V$ be the given vertex set.

Denote by $p_{uv}$ the probability of having an edge between two vertices $u$ and $v$.  Let $I_{uv} = 1$ if $u, v$ are neighbors, and $0$ otherwise.  And let $X_v$ be a random variable corresponding to the number of neighbors in $S$ of some vertex $v$.

Using linearity of expectation, the expected value is

$$\mathbb{E}[X_v] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{u \in S} I_{uv} \right] = \sum_{u \in S}\mathbb{E} [I_{uv}] = \sum_{u \in S} p_{uv}$$

That's for a specific $v$.  Now, let $X$ be the random variable for the number of neighbors of a randomly picked vertex.  I assume that each vertex has an equal probability $1/n$ of being chosen, $n$ being the number of vertices in $V$.

We have

$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{v \in V} \frac{1}{n} \mathbb{E}[X_v] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{v \in V} \sum_{u \in S} p_{uv}
$$

So in the end, you can just sum up the values in the $S$ columns of your matrix, then divide that by $n$.

Comment: That's great, thanks.  But I had figured out that much myself -- it is the basis of the simulation technique where I take several random draws of $S$.  What I'm having trouble with is for an $S$ constructed of an arbitrary selection of nodes.  What I want is $E[X] = f(N)$, where N is the number of elements of $S$.  I'll amend my question accordingly.

Comment: Oh sorry about that...I didn't know you wanted the answer as a function of $N$.  So if I get it right, you want $\mathbb{E}[X | S $ has $N$ elements $]$ ?  If so, that seems A LOT harder...

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much.  It might have been one of those things that some smart person has already figured out, so I figured I'd ask.  I've already simulated, though it is really slow to do as a routine calculation.

Comment: But I guess you're better off simulating it anyway.  It should be feasible is every edge had the same probability, but as your probability matrix is arbitrary, I can't see a way to avoid going through all possible subsets of size $N$, as you added in your question.